# How to get first 5 maximum values from numpy array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max, numpy-ndarray

```
x = np.array([3, 4, 2, 1, 7, 8, 6, 5, 9])
```

I want to get an answer as `array([9,8,7,6,5])` and their indices `array([8,5,4,6,7])`.

I've tried `np.amax` which only provides a single value.

Comment: See `np.partition` and `np.sort`. If you want the indices, see `np.argpartition` and `np.argsort`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this (each step is commented for clarity):

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([3, 4, 2, 1, 7, 8, 6, 5, 9])

y = x.copy() # <----optional, create a copy of the array
y = np.sort(x) # sort array
y = y[::-1] # reverse sort order
y = y[0:5] # take a slice of the first 5
print(y)
```

The result:

```
[9 8 7 6 5]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is pretty straightforward but unfortunately, I am working with the pixels and I don't want to mess with the main indices of the array by sorting. Can you suggest any other method, please?

Comment: if you wanted to, you can crete a copy of an array such that the new array does not intefere with the old array. And it would literally be as simple as this:  `new_list = old_list.copy()`.  I have added one line of code to reflect this into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.argsort` to get the sorted indices. Any by doing `-x` you can get them in descending order:

```
indices = np.argsort(-x)
```

You can get the numbers by doing:

```
sorted_values = x[indices]
```

You can then get the slice of just the top 5 by doing:

```
top5 = sorted_values[:5]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please suggest other methods? I'm working with the pixels here so I don't want to mess up with the main indices by sorting.